# Redirect category to a static page

Tags: magento, redirect, categories

Is it possible to redirect some specific category to a static page?

So far I tried to do it with custom redirect but it complains about non-unique request path. Target path is disabled when editing category rewrite too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's possible but not without writing some custom code and adding an observer.

Without entering in much detail you could :

```
public function observe($observer) {
   $request = $observer['controller_action']->getRequest();
   $requestUrl = $request->getRequestUri();

   if($requestUrl == 'mycategoryname'){
       $destinationUrl = 'http://www.mysite.com/static_page';
       $response = Mage::app()->getResponse();
       $response->setRedirect($destinationUrl, 301);
       $response->sendResponse();
       exit;
   }
 }
```

And on the config.xml you are going to need

```
<frontend>
  <events>
    <controller_action_predispatch>
       <observers>
         <mycompany_mymodule_model_myclass>
          <type>singleton</type>
          <class>mycompany_mymodule_model_myclass</class>
          <method>observe</method>
         </mycompany_mymodule_model_myclass>
       </observers>
     </controller_action_predispatch>
   </events>
 </frontend>
```

Comment: thanks, but what if I need it for several say 3-4 categories? Really hoped custom redirect could work

Comment: Do your categories really need to exist? If the answer is not there might be a solution for this issue.

Comment: Actually yes, we did it with a static link. Thanks for input!

Answer (score 0):

Just came across this. I'm doing the same thing essentially and just had a thought that maybe this could be accomplished relatively easily with a module that adds a category attribute along with some additional and/or custom code for the nav bar.

I'm thinking that a new category attribute could be the url to rewrite to, and then a check in the navigation/top.phtml template to check if that attribute is filled in and then rewrite to that url if so.

I'll post here later if I get this to work as desired.